Cannot create account for a token in CLI
I've tried three times and always get the same error:
spl-token create-account oreoN2tQbHXVaZsr3pf66A48miqcBXCDJozganhEJgz
Creating account 28AAsPi2C7PBk8nLqC61t7TEUtweqW5tT2rzGHf9fjtq
Error: Client(Error { request: None, kind: RpcError(ForUser("unable to confirm transaction. This can happen in situations such as transaction expiration and insufficient fee-payer funds")) })

What should I do to fix this? Or is this related to current congestion issues?
The wallet has 0,02 SOL balance.

Dude, I'm having a similar error trying to create token on Devnet.. Here is mine, if you want follow it. I'll be following yours. https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/12689/error-minting-token-on-devnet If you're on Mainnet I would guess its due the ridiculous network congestion as of late. But someone smarter than me may have a better answer.

I am having the same issue as well.

If you're using mainnet, be sure to add a priority fee to your transaction using the --with-compute-unit-price and --with-compute-unit-limit flags, ie:
spl-token create-account oreoN2tQbHXVaZsr3pf66A48miqcBXCDJozganhEJgz \
  --with-compute-unit-price 10

If you want to spend 10 micro-lamports per compute unit.
