Error minting token on Devnet
Noob here, in a bootcamp. Gettin stuck with this error. I have set configuration successfully to Devnet. But then things like requesting Airdrop from Devnet or spl-token create-token are giving me the following error and I'm not certain how to proceed. ChatGPT was not helpful.
See here I am confugired:

Then see here that I'm getting error:

Thanks!

I got it to work somehow. I was digging around and saw a post where someone was saying you need to run "solana-test-validator".
So I did that it's going forever. It just keeps confirming slots. What exactly am I doing by running "solana-test-validator"?

I opened a 2nd terminal and config set to Devnet and it did not work at first. Came back an hour later and was successful in Airdropping Sol, creating, minting and transferring my new token. so yay!

Real curious to hear some thoughts to understand what is happening a bit better. Thank you!
